# Install roles and membership to a specific database in command prompt

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I would like to install membership and roles to a specific database. It seems to create a new database : `aspnetdb`. I tried using the GUI (Wizard) but that installed personalization. I tried adding "...Localhost/DatabaseName"  but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the command-line options at [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx)

Specifically, **-d** *<database>*:

> Specifies the name of the database to
>   create or modify for use with
>   application services. If the database
>   is not specified, the default database
>   name of "aspnetdb" is used.